# JPA throws java.lang.StackOverflowError with bidirectional @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have two entity classes as follows. The `Parachute` is the parent object and it has multiple `Component` objects. I need to have bidirectional @OneToMany implemented here.

Parent `Parachute.java` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parachute")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Parachute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parachute",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addComponent(Component component) {
        components.add(component);
        component.setParachute(this);
    }

}
```

Child `Component.java` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parachute_id")
    private Parachute parachute;
}
```

I tried to add a Parachute as follows.

```
Component component1 = new Component();
component1.setSerialNumber("12121999");

Component component2 = new Component();
component2.setSerialNumber("12121910");

Parachute parachute = new Parachute();
parachute.setName("new Para");

parachute.addComponent(component1);
parachute.addComponent(component2)

parachuteRepository.save(parachute);
```

This gives me a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Am I doing this wrong or is there any other way to do this?

Please refer to the below stack trace. The same track has been repeated multiple times.

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:304)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1334)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:249)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.findUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService.getLoggedInUser(AuditService.java:61)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$93425db9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41cc04e5.getLoggedInUser(<generated>)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.component.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.getCurrentAuditor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.getAuditor(AuditingHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markCreated(AuditingHandler.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate(AuditingEntityListener.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.findUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService.getLoggedInUser(AuditService.java:61)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$93425db9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.service.AuditService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41cc04e5.getLoggedInUser(<generated>)
    at com.techilasoftware.parachute.app.component.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.getCurrentAuditor(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using Lombok @Data annotation?

Comment: It may not be related, but you refer to `Parachute` in your `@JoinColumn` with `parachute_id`, which does not appear nor exists in the code you show. And the stack trace seems to indicate that you get an error in `AuditService.getUserLoggedIn()`, which does not look like a place where you would add parachutes and components.

Comment: I have been using Lombok @Data previously and removed that but still no luck. I use `AuditingEntityListener` for auditing and overridden the `AuditorAware` interface to get the actual logged-in `User` model for auditing. `AuditService.getUserLoggedIn()` is a method I have used for that.

Comment: `parachute_id` is the column I use to implement the many-to-one relationship at the child side.

Comment: Will it fail if you comment out `@EntityListeners`?

Comment: @pirho that did the trick, and it is working fine. Wondering what the issue is since I need to map the actual `User` for `createdAt` and `modifiedAt `columns.

Comment: It might have something to do with serializing entity. Maybe there is a hint on your auditing config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violating the JPA spec by accessing the persistence context in a lifecycle listener.

See the JPA Specification 4.2 Section 3.5.2

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
> state of the entity on which it is invoked.

"a portable application should not" is the specification way of saying: Don't do that, anything might happen. Maybe the world ends.

The fix is not to do that. Maybe be preloading the currently logged in user and reference it so you may access it in your entity listener and do not set a reference to the user, but simple store its id or similar.